# C++ Reading labeled data from file

Tags: c++

I have a file with labeled data such as:

```
Label1,0.002546,0.054126,...
...
...
LabelN,0.025413,0.985412,...
```

What I want is to store labels to `std::vector<std::string>` and data to `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` So, this is what I tried:

```
input.open(files.at(0));

while (std::getline(input, line)) {

    std::istringstream is(line);

    // Get label
    labels.push_back( *(++std::istream_iterator<string>(is)) );

    // Get data
    data.push_back(std::vector<double>( ++std::istream_iterator<double>(is), std::istream_iterator<double>()));

}
```

But, this isn't working and I keep getting

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>   Program: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP120D.dll 
>   File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\vector 
>   Line: 72 
>   Expression: vector iterator not dereferencable

Comment: @underscore_d That's what visual studio pop up window says.

Comment: Using temporary iterators looks really suspicious.  I would make `std::istream_iterator<string>(is)` a named variable in the loop and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I'm sure you can find line 72 in your own code much faster than anyone on stackoverflow.com can figure out.

Comment: @NathanOliver I will give a try

Comment: Also, I really can't figure out what that `vector` constructor is supposed to be doing, from `is` and a temporary default iterator; can you explain?

Comment: Which part of the shown code divides each line into separate values separated by commas, here? If you expect C++ to do it automatically for you, I'm going to have to disappoint you.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think line 72 is for the `..\include\vector ` file, not my file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `istream_iterator<string>` will consume the whole line; you need to tokenize on `,` somehow, e.g.:

```
std::istringstream is(line);
data.push_back({});

std::string token;
std::getline(is, token, ',');
labels.push_back(token);
while (std::getline(is, token, ',')) {
    double v;
    std::istringstream(token) >> v;

    data.back().push_back(v);
}
```

Note that the slightly cryptic double parsing could be replaced by e.g. `boost::lexical_cast` or similar helper.

Comment: Although now that I wrote that I think writing `separated_iterator<T, char>` could be a nice excercise

Comment: Okay, I did it your way. Now I don't any errors, but it reads only the first number of every row

Comment: I fixed it and it works perfectly. Thank you very much